# Swift - passing text and int from vc1 to vc 2 (uitextfield -> label in vc2)

Tags: swift

Passing only input text from textfield to label in second VC works!! But i want when user type number 10 in uitextfield, ( 1 ticket is 2 euros so 10 tickets * 2 euro is 20) and when i click PAY button, so that SUM can be displayed in label in second VC, i think that viewdidload in VC2 is happening before prepareForSegue, i don't know. It works when i click second time on PAY button, but not when i first click PAY button where label displays zero, help :)  Embedded in navigation controller for navigation.

[image: 1]

VC1

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var howManyTickets: UITextField!

var sumTicketsAndPriceOfTickets = Int()
var priceOfTicket = 2 // euros

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func platiTeKarte(sender: AnyObject) {

    sumTicketsAndPriceOfTickets = howManyTickets.text.toInt()! * priceOfTicket

    }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let driver = segue.destinationViewController as! primaocViewController

    var whatToPass = sumTicketsAndPriceOfTickets

    driver.receiver = whatToPass
}
}
```

VC2

```
import UIKit

class primaocViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var displaySum: UILabel!

var receiver:Int!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.displaySum.text = String(receiver)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your button is wired directly to a segue, then you don't need an @IBAction as well.  As you are seeing, the `prepareForSegue` is happening before the @IBAction for your Pay button.  Just compute your value in `prepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let driver = segue.destinationViewController as! primaocViewController

    driver.receiver = (howManyTickets.text.toInt() ?? 0) * priceOfTicket
}
```

I changed the calculation of the pay to use the *nil coalescing operator* `??`.  This is generally a safer approach because if the `toInt()` returns `nil` for any reason, it will in this case just use `0` instead of crashing.

Comment: thank you , even more simple :), or i could pass number 10 tickets to second VC and calculate there,.. thanks again! EDIT: It works like this also driver.receiver = (howManyTickets.text.toInt())! * priceOfTicket